# Aggregating values from the UNION set operator

Tags: mysql, sql, union, sql-null

How should we need to aggregate values, in case, if there are two values in a single column and the rest of the columns contains NULL values, then all the values need to get grouped as well as rest of the column should display NULL as the values

We need to iterate each column value, moving to the top and shifting the NULL values next/bottom to that particular value if there are two values in a single column and the rest of the columns contains NULL values, then all the values need to be shifted to the top leaving rest of the NULL values at the bottom and if there are no values in a row, then it should simply display as NULL

Consider the simple SQL query

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  (
    (SELECT
      6 + 2 AS val1,
      NULL AS val2,
      NULL AS val3,
      NULL AS val4,
      5 + 5 AS val5,
      NULL AS val6
    FROM
      DUAL)
    UNION
    (SELECT
      NULL AS val1,
      6 - 2 AS val2,
      NULL AS val3,
      NULL AS val4,
      9 - 3 AS val5,
      7 - 3 AS val6
    FROM
      DUAL)
    UNION
    (SELECT
      NULL AS val1,
      NULL AS val2,
      6 * 2 AS val3,
      NULL AS val4,
      NULL AS val5,
      NULL AS val6
    FROM
      DUAL)
    UNION
    (SELECT
      NULL AS val1,
      NULL AS val2,
      NULL AS val3,
      6 / 2 AS val4,
      NULL AS val5,
      NULL AS val6
    FROM
      DUAL)
  ) A;
```

**Actual Result:**

```
+------+------+------+--------+------+------+
| val1 | val2 | val3 | val4   | val5 | val6 |
+------+------+------+--------+------+------+
|    8 | NULL | NULL |   NULL |   10 | NULL |
| NULL |    4 | NULL |   NULL |    6 |    4 |
| NULL | NULL |   12 |   NULL | NULL | NULL |
| NULL | NULL | NULL | 3.0000 | NULL | NULL |
+------+------+------+--------+------+------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Expected Result:**

```
+------+------+------+--------+------+------+
| val1 | val2 | val3 | val4   | val5 | val6 |
+------+------+------+--------+------+------+
|    8 |    4 | 12   | 3.0000 |   10 |    4 |
| NULL | NULL | NULL |   NULL |    6 | NULL |
+------+------+------+--------+------+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

---

### [SQL Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e4349a1f90e017eaf77cfd7ffdbb1b09)

**EDIT:**

As Gordon Linoff, said it is possible in MySQL 8+ by using row_number() and joins
As I'm expecting a precise solution meeting the expected result via SQL Demo. Since the post is on hold

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets, so there is no "moving" up unless a column specifies the ordering.

Comment: How should we need to approach this scenario @GordonLinoff

Comment: Why do you even need to do this ? Please tell the practical use-case instead. This is not how relational data (tables) work; a row with all its fields (columns) are connected together, as a specific data; you cannot just dislocate them like a Rubik's cube.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL 8+, you can use `row_number()` and joins:

```
select t1.val1, t2.val2, t3.val3, . . .
from (select row_number() over (order by (val1 is not null asc) as seqnum, t.*
      from t
     ) t1 join
     (select row_number() over (order by (val2 is not null asc) as seqnum, t.*
      from t
     ) t2
     on t1.seqnum = t2.seqnum join
     (select row_number() over (order by (val3 is not null asc) as seqnum, t.*
      from t
     ) t3
     on t1.seqnum = t3.seqnum join
     . . .
order by t1.seqnum;
```

This does not preserve the original ordering of the rows.  It simply moves the `NULL` values to the "end".

Comment: Will you try to run with this [SQL Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e4349a1f90e017eaf77cfd7ffdbb1b09) I'm not getting how should I need to adopt to my SQL

Comment: @Nishanthॐ . . . Put your values into a table or use a CTE.

Comment: What does that suppose to mean How do we need to implement it

Answer (score 0):

Well you can try using `GROUP_CONCAT()`

```
Select 
  GROUP_CONCAT(val1) as val1,
  GROUP_CONCAT(val2) as val2,
  GROUP_CONCAT(val3) as val3,
  GROUP_CONCAT(val4) as val4,
  GROUP_CONCAT(val5) as val5,
  GROUP_CONCAT(val6) as val6
FROM
  (
    (SELECT
      6 + 2 AS val1,
      NULL AS val2,
      NULL AS val3,
      NULL AS val4,
      5 + 5 AS val5,
      NULL AS val6
    FROM
      DUAL)
    UNION
    (SELECT
      NULL AS val1,
      6 - 2 AS val2,
      NULL AS val3,
      NULL AS val4,
      9 - 3 AS val5,
      7 - 3 AS val6
    FROM
      DUAL)
    UNION
    (SELECT
      NULL AS val1,
      NULL AS val2,
      6 * 2 AS val3,
      NULL AS val4,
      NULL AS val5,
      NULL AS val6
    FROM
      DUAL)
    UNION
    (SELECT
      NULL AS val1,
      NULL AS val2,
      NULL AS val3,
      6 / 2 AS val4,
      NULL AS val5,
      NULL AS val6
    FROM
      DUAL)
  ) A;
```

[SQL Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4025056549e1baf8af9a9b49d979a874)